# App's cache is unintentionally deleted in Oxygen OS 13

Tags: caching, oneplusx

I'm developping in Flutter and i debug my app in my real device, an OnePlus 8T. After i update to Oxygen OS 13, the app's local cache is deleted unintentionally, what makes that I can´t record any long videos. The images and whatever stay in the cache, is deleted too.
I tried to execute the app in another device with Android 9,in emulator with Android 13,12,11 and 10.
In Realme GT with Android 13 too. And in all of these devices, this problem not occurr. All works correctly.

Before upgrading to Oxygen OS 13, i remind that the cache folder worked fine.

I tried to take pictures or record videos with any library which can do this.

**Expected behavior**
The pictures and the videos are saved in the local cache.

**Actual behavior**
The pictures are deleted and the video sometimes can´t be recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgrade to Oxygen OS 12 and the error is gone.